# Flutter WebRTC - Multiple commands produce XCode

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, ios, xcode

Estoy tratando de agregar el plugin `flutter_webrtc` pero al tratar de compilar para `iOS` obtengo el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y para `Android` algo muy parecido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acutalizado:

Problema resuelto, lo que sucede es que tenía la [swarm_cloud](https://pub.dev/packages/swarm_cloud) para coneccion p2p de multimedia, la cual generaba el error.
La quite y ahora todo va bien.
Por si a alguien mas le pasa. Puede ser que algunas de sus dependencias esta causando conflictos en tiempo de compilacion.

Comment: ¿Usas emulador o dispositivo real?

Comment: Simulador iOS y emulador Android...

Comment: Por descartar, ¿Te has leído la doc del plugin? Pone que hay que hacer algunas configuraciones para ambas plataformas.

Comment: @Manuel claro que si. Tengo todas las configuraciones hechas.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Java usas? El plugin, según leo necesita la 11. Está complicado ayudarte, es un error bastante extraño, así que tendrás que ir descartando posibles problemas hasta que encuentres el fallo.

Comment: @Manuel muchas gracias, ya encontré la solución y actualice mi pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Parece ser que es un problema del package, mira, en uno de sus issues cerrados, una persona tenia el mismo problema que tù y el tuvo que cambiar de canal de desarrollo
El tenía este problema:

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/johnjelinek/Documents/code/flutter-webrtc/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework':
    1) Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/johnjelinek/Documents/code/flutter-webrtc/example/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework' to '/Users/johnjelinek/Documents/code/flutter-webrtc/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'
    2) That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
    warning: ignoring duplicated output file: '/Users/johnjelinek/Documents/code/flutter-webrtc/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework' (in target 'Runner')
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone XS Max.
```

https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc/issues/13#issuecomment-425307781
Revisa ese hilo , pero básicamente lo que el describe es que lo solucionó haciendo esto :

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda